# How can I include test-coverage reports in my C# SonarQube project?

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I currently have a build file that results in basic-analysis report on my SonarQube server.

```
MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:"mykey" /n:"myname" /v:"1.0.0"
msbuild ... # build production code
MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end
msbuild ... # build test code
OpenCover ... # run test code and generate a (non-SonarQube) coverage report
```

So far so good.  Now I would like to add test-coverage reports to the mix.  This is where I am stuck.  How can I include test-coverage reports in my C# SonarQube project?

I have tried two ways to get test-coverage reports, but neither have the desired effect:

1. run two separate MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe sessions, one for analyzing the production code and another for handling the test-coverage report; with this approach I see no errors, see basic analysis, but see no test-coverage reports:

   ```
   MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:"mykey" /n:"myname" /v:"1.0.0"
   msbuild ... # build production code
   MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end
   MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:"mykey" /n:"myname" /v:"1.0.0" /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths="opencover.xml" /d:sonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths="nunit.xml"
   msbuild ... # build test code
   OpenCover ... # run test code and generate a (non-SonarQube) coverage report
   MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end
   ```
2. expand the original MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe session to include the test-related build code; with this approach I see no errors, but also see **NO** reports:

   ```
   MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:"mykey" /n:"myname" /v:"1.0.0" /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths="opencover.xml" /d:sonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths="nunit.xml"
   msbuild ... # build production code
   msbuild ... # build test code
   OpenCover ... # run test code and generate a (non-SonarQube) coverage report
   MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end
   ```

#### Technical background

- SonarQube 5.1.2
- C# Plugin 5.2
- MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner 1.0.1
- NUnit.Runners.Net45.x64 2.6.3
- OpenCover 4.5.3207

#### My background

- I am experienced in Java and Java with SonarQube but new to C# and C# with SonarQube.
- I have read

  - http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/C%23+Plugin ,
  - http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/C%23+Code+Coverage+Results+Import ,
  - http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/sq-setup-guide-for-dotnet-users.html .

#### Other background

- I separate my production code and test code in two separate FS trees with two separate .csproj files.
- I identify my test project, which has a MyTests.csproj project file, to SonarQube as a test project in two ways:

  1. I set sonar.cs.msbuild.testProjectPattern to `[^\\]*Test[^\\]*$` on the SonarQube server and
  2. I add `<SonarQubeTestProject>true</SonarQubeTestProject>` to the unconditional PropertyGroup in MyTests.csproj.

Answer (score 3):

The first approach--run MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe twice, once around the build and once around the testing--works; the second approach does not.

The key here is to provide MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe with correct paths to the test-report XML files.  I wast providing it with incorrect paths, and that doesn't work.